# If I am using a git repository, how can I rewrite mod so it doesn't show subfolder in url?

Tags: git, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using codeigniter framework. linux server.

Let's say I have a http://www.domain.com

I have a bitbucket repository named domain_test and when I git clone the directory, it creates a folder public_html/domain_test

In order for me to make it so when the user types in domain.com and goes to domain_test folder right away I have following in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /domain_test/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The only problem is when someone goes to http://www.domain.com or domain.com it will show http://www.domain.com/domain_test

Is there a way to make look like http://www.domain.com without seeing domain_test in url?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `R=301` so the rewrite is done internally without sending a 301 redirect to the browser.

Comment: The thing is that works but as soon as you click on any link it will be domain.com/domain_test/any_link_you_clicked in the url... is there a way to do it so it's domain.com/any_link_you_clicked_after

Comment: Ideally you would have a way to change the links so they don't include `domain_test`, then the rewrite you have would be enough. If that isn't an option you need to first create a redirect, then allow the rewrite rule above to handle the request.  But the user will _still_ see `domain_test` when mousing over the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule (?!^domain_test(/.*|)$)^(.*)$ /domain_test/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: domain.com didn't redirect to domain.com/domain_test/

Comment: This will not redirect externally but will do an internal forward only. In other words `domain.com` will show content of `domain.com/domain_test/` but URL in browser remain `domain.com`.

Comment: ah ok you forgot to include RewriteEngine On in your code. How is this different from RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /domain_test/ [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Oh you already had `RewriteEngine On` in your question so I assumed its already there. Your rule is just forwarding (internally) `domain.com/` to `domain.com/domain_test/` but your rule will *NOT* forward `domain.com/index.html` to `domain.com/domain_test/index.html` but my rule above will take care of that scenario as well.